# Synology NAS station - how to mirror 2 HDD (Simple how-to)

Tags: hard-drive, backup, raid, nas

I have the following problem with my Synology disk station:

- I had one small HDD in Synology Diskstation, so I removed it.
- I bought 2 new HDD with the same capacity.
- I transferred backup from old disk to new and inserted this new disc
  into Synology.
- Synology works fine with one HDD but is not backed up, so I want to
  add a second HDD which should be used as mirror for HDD 1 (if one
  from discs will crash second will hold all data in copy, I just
  replace faulty HDD).

Problem is that I can choose between adding new volume or I can create disc group.

I don't know what is suitable for me, so I tried both solutions but without luck.

Could somebody tell me, what exactly should I do and what I should choose as backup for my needs?

**NOTE:** 
First disc is from 50 percent full of data, second disc is empty. I think that better is have copy 1:1 so second dis will be copy of the first disc.

Comment: Have you found your solution for this? I'm in the same boat. Would like to know what you found out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [Change Your Volume Diskgroup Type](https://help.synology.com/dsm/?section=DSM&version=5.0&link=StorageManager%2Fvolume_diskgroup_change_raid_type.html) to RAID 1

From the page:

```
In the example below, we will change a Basic volume to a RAID 1 volume.
Before You Start:

    Make sure the status of your volume or disk group is Normal.
    When adding new hard drives to a volume or disk group, the new hard drives must be larger than the smallest hard drive in the volume or disk group.
    The status of new hard drives must be Initialized or Not Initialized.

To change the RAID type of a volume:

    Open Storage Manager.
    Go to Volume. (If you want to change the RAID type of a disk group, then go to the Disk Group tab.)
    Select the volume you wish to change and click Manage.
    When the setup wizard appears, select Change RAID type. Then click Next.
    Select the RAID type to which you want to change the volume. Click Next.
    Select which hard drive(s) to add to the existing volume. Then click Next.
    Follow the instructions of the wizard to finish. Please note existing data on the added hard drive shall be deleted.
```

Comment: Hello, thanks. Do You think that RAID 1 is better (means safer), that Synology Hybrid Raid?

Comment: And should i create 2 volumes or one group?

Comment: I believe it'll be one volume. That one volume is currently a Basic Volume, you'll make it a RAID 1 volume by adding another HDD to the volume and changing it's type. As for SHR vs RAID 1, I'm not at all familiar with their RAID solution, but if it at all differs from RAID 1, I'd likely prefer RAID 1 in case data recovery efforts necessitate using hardware other than a Synology box.

Comment: Note please, that RAID **never** replaces a backup.